# Can I suppress autocomplete of a certain category in zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

When I attempt to autocomplete `ssh` in `zsh`, I am presented with two types of lists.

```
$ ssh a<TAB>
 -- remote host name --
aur
 -- login name --
avahi
```

However, the latter is not useful to me. Is it possible to suppress everything under `-- login name --`, leaving only entries under `-- remote host name --`?

I also get multiple entries when using rsync, although the headings differ.

```
$ rsync a<TAB>
 -- user --
avahi
 -- host --
aur
```

I'd like to suppress entries under `-- user --` here.

---

### Possibly pertinent information

I use `zim`. Also, the following is in `~/.zshrc`.

```
h=()
if [[ -r ~/.ssh/config ]]; then
  h=($h ${${${(@M)${(f)"$(cat ~/.ssh/config)"}:#Host *}#Host }:#*[*?]*})
fi
if [[ $#h -gt 0 ]]; then
  zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*' hosts $h
  zstyle ':completion:*:slogin:*' hosts $h
  zstyle ':completion:*:rsync:*' hosts $h
fi
```

This a workaround for a [bug](https://github.com/Eriner/zim/issues/46) in `zim` where tab completion works with hostnames instead of hosts.

Comment: OT: there's [zim](https://github.com/Eriner/zim), and then there's [zim](http://zim-wiki.org/). :)  I presume you mean the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `users` style:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' users
```

Setting an empty list like this disables completion on user names. You can narrow it down to individual commands, if you like:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:rsync:*' users
```

for example, would disable it for `rsync` but leave it on elsewhere.

The zsh completion system is very sophisticated, and its configuration complex. The `zshcompsys` man page covers the new style of completion, as demonstrated here, and the `zstyle` command is documented in the `zshmodules` man page.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly (+1)! Could you please put some information in about that command, and/or a link? Also, would it have been possible to deduct that the relevant style was called `users`, when (as per the question) it was presented under the headings of `login name` and `user`? Or is it just something you had to know prior?

Comment: Added details of where you can find more documentation. I think you'd probably need a little prior knowledge to know which completer to use in this case.